# Сбор статистики частот биграмм

Tags: алгоритм, криптография, статистика

Доброго времени суток, уважаемое сообщество. У меня к вам вопрос не касающийся программирования, но, возможно, кто-то из вас уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Я пишу программу для дешифрования шифра простой замены с помощью частотного анализа. Я решил дешифровать по частотам биграмм. Но вместо использования готовой статистики по частотам, мне хотелось бы собрать свою. То есть я буду вводить тексты на русском, программа будет считать частоту биграмм в них и обновлять таблицу статистики в файле. Вот, собственно, и сам вопрос: как мне обновить статистику? Первой мыслью было взять среднее арифметическое частоты биграммы из файла и из текста, и записать в статистику. Но это явно не то.

P.S. Простите, что вопрос не по теме, просто больше негде искать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Что вообще такое частота в контексте сбора этой статистики?**

Это отношение количества в тексте биграмм *с одним конкретным значением* к *общему* количеству всех биграмм.

---

Так, у нас есть два текста и некая биграмма X.

Для первого текста, в котором всего N<sub>1</sub> биграмм и N<sub>1X</sub> биграмм Х, частота равна P<sub>1X</sub>=N<sub>2X</sub>/N<sub>1</sub>.
Для второго текста, соответственно, P<sub>2X</sub>=N<sub>2X</sub>/N<sub>2</sub>.

Теперь у нас есть сумма этих двух текстов. Грубо считаем, что конкатенация без учёта биграмм на стыке.

То, что мы хотим получить, выглядит как (N<sub>1X</sub> + N<sub>2X</sub>)/(N<sub>1</sub> + N<sub>2</sub>): сколько всего раз эта биграмма встречается, разделить на общее число биграмм в текстах. Очевидно, среднее арифметическое P<sub>1X</sub> и P<sub>1X</sub> даст нечто совсем другое. Более того, видно, что одних частот знать недостаточно, нужно ещё как минимум знать общее число биграмм в обоих текстах.

Вам нужно [**среднее взвешенное**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5), где весами будут объёмы (в биграммах) соответствующих текстов. Собственно, если в формуле выше выразить количества через частоты, получится прямо оно:

> (P<sub>1X</sub>N<sub>1</sub> + P<sub>2X</sub>N<sub>2</sub>)/(N<sub>1</sub> + N<sub>2</sub>)

...и это всё красиво и мило, если вычисления абсолютно точные. Но если вы не можете позволить себе считать вероятности с произвольной точностью, лучше хранить непосредственно количества конкретных биграмм и их общее число. Или наоборот, если вы хотите ускорить обработку чисел ценой возникновения некоторой погрешности, можно хранить вероятности в типе с ограниченной точностью.

Comment: Все работает, большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 4):

В принципе, задача сводиться к тому, как посчитать среднее арифметическое, не запоминая всех измерений.

Когда то давно у меня был калькулятор, который умел считать средне арифметическое массива чисел. Я долго думал, что он запоминает все числа, но у него явно не было сколько памяти. Я так и не знаю, как именно он считал это, но я нашел три способа

- запоминаем не среднее, а сумму и количество. А среднее всегда можно посчитать
- считаем по следующей формуле "новое среднее" = ("старое среднее" * "кол-во" + текущее) / ("кол-во" + 1). где "кол-во" - это количество чисел, для которых уже посчитали среднее.

Но эти два способа имеют существенный недостаток. Если числа для которых находиться среднее находятся в слишком большом диапазоне, то они будут давать слишком большую погрешность.

Поэтому приходит на помощь третий способ  суммировать числа, поделив их на две (или три) группы. В одной суммируются большие числа, в второй - маленькие.

В целом, я думаю, что для Вашего случая просто запоминайте общее количество найденных пар. Когда получите статистику по очередному тексту, то просто подсуммируйте кол-во пар по каждой паре. Само количество можно смело хранить в обычном int, скорее всего его хватит.